# How to count words in a text file, java 8-style

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, word-count

I'm trying to perform an assignment that first counts the number of files in a directory and then give a word count within each file. I got the file count alright, but I'm having a hard time converting some code my instructor gave me from a class that does a frequency count to the simpler word count. Moreover, I can't seem to find the proper code to look at each file to count the words (I'm trying to find something "generic" rather than a specific, but I trying to test the program using a specific text file). This is the intended output:

```
Count 11 files:
word length: 1 ==> 80
word length: 2 ==> 321
word length: 3 ==> 643
```

However, this is what's being outputted instead:

```
primes.txt
but
are
sometimes
sense
refrigerator
make
haiku
dont
they
funny
word length: 1 ==> {but=1, are=1, sometimes=1, sense=1, refrigerator=1, make=1, haiku=1, dont=1, they=1, funny=1}

.....

Count 11 files:
```

I'm using two classes: WordCount and FileCatch8

WordCount:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

    /**
     *
     * @author 
     */
    public class WordCount {

        /**
         *
         * @param filename
         * @return
         * @throws java.io.IOException
         */
        public Map<String, Long> count(String filename) throws IOException {
            //Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename));
            Path path = Paths.get("haiku.txt");
            Map<String, Long> wordMap = Files.lines(path)
                    .parallel()
                    .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.trim().split(" ")))
                    .map(word -> word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase().trim())
                    .filter(word -> word.length() > 0)
                    .map(word -> new SimpleEntry<>(word, 1))
                    //.collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> 1, Integer::sum));
                    .collect(groupingBy(SimpleEntry::getKey, counting()));

            wordMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(String.format(k,v)));
            return wordMap;
        }
    }
```

And FileCatch:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class FileCatch8 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream
        (Paths.get("files"));
            int fileCounter = 0;
            WordCount wordCnt = new WordCount();
            for (Path path : directoryStream) {
                System.out.println(path.getFileName());
                fileCounter++;
                fileNames.add(path.getFileName().toString()); 
                System.out.println("word length: " +  fileCounter + " ==> " + 
                        wordCnt.count(path.getFileName().toString()));
}
        } catch(IOException ex){
    }
    System.out.println("Count: "+fileNames.size()+ " files");

  }
}
```

The program uses Java 8 streams with lambda syntax

Comment: Does, new SimpleEntry<>(word, 1) set the map value to 1 each time?

Comment: You could use Function.identity() without creating SimpleEntry and using of SimpleEntry::getKey. For simpler file counting try to look at Files.walk... .

Comment: I think it does. Is it wrong to do it like that?

Comment: It is not rational.

Comment: @egorlitvinenko I can say with true sincerity, my instructor wrote that code! :)

Comment: @JavaNewbie if you want to become a good programmer, you always should learn at your own too. :)

Comment: One question: The files count example. Are these for the other FileCount class?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you question. Could you explain what do you mean? I don't see FileCount class in standard Java library.

Comment: Are these two lines to be put in the FileCount class of my program?

Comment: Oh, I'm trying to point that Files in Java 8 has good API. For your particular task you could use ...count() to count files and Files.walkFileTree for counting words, for example, or you could use only streams. I think final implementation you should find by own.:) One of problem in your implementation that you also don't need Collectors.groupingBy, because in intended result you have only count. So just count() would be enough. Another problem, that you have not correct output sequence.

Comment: I've tried these solutions, but I'm just getting nowhere. Theres multiple errors

Answer (score 7):

Word count example:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(file))
    .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.trim().split(" ")))
    .map(word -> word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase().trim())
    .filter(word -> !word.isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Files count:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(file), Integer.MAX_VALUE).count();
Files.walk(Paths.get(file)).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the simplest way to count the words in a file using Java 8 is this:

```
Long wordsCount = Files.lines(Paths.get(file))
    .flatMap(str->Stream.of(str.split("[ ,.!?\r\n]")))
    .filter(s->s.length()>0).count();
System.out.println(wordsCount);
```

And to count all the files:

```
Long filesCount = Files.walk(Paths.get(file)).count();
System.out.println(filesCount);
```

Comment: That's nice, but if you want to count a directory of files, don't you have to use DirectoryStream?

Comment: Yes you can iterate over the entries in a directory using DirectoryStream. I just showed you another approach.