# How to count files and count words in a set of files Using Java 8 and Streams

Tags: java, file, lambda, java-8

I'm having a tough time. I'm trying to finish an assignment in which a directory of files is accessed and the files count, then the files themselves are read and the words are counted in each file. This is the continuation of a question I've posted, but the "answers" didn't help resolve my problem at all ([How to count words in a text file, java 8-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594679/how-to-count-words-in-a-text-file-java-8-style/47604839?noredirect=1#comment82215676_47604839))

This is the problem outline:

Write a program that uses streams to efficiently count the words of different lengths appear in the a set of files (files.zip).  Your output look like: (the count numbers are only for illustrating purpose).

```
Count 11 files:
word length: 1 ==> 80
word length: 2 ==> 321
word length: 3 ==> 643

Instead, I got the following output:

primes.txt
Count: 1 files
```

This is the code I've wrote. I've used two classes FileReader which is the main class that reads a directory named "Files:

```
FileReader.java

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    /**
     *
     * @author 
     */
    public class FileReader {

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("files"));
                int fileCounter = 0;
                **WordReader wordCnt = new WordReader();**
                for (Path path : directoryStream) {
                    System.out.println(path.getFileName());
                    fileCounter++;
                    fileNames.add(path.getFileName().toString());
                    **System.out.println("word length: " + fileCounter + " ==> "
                            + wordCnt.count(path.getFileName().toString()));**
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
            System.out.println("Count: " + fileNames.size() + " files");

        }
    }
```

And the WordReader class which, in theory, should count the words within each file in the directory. The class in written in lambda syntax:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Map;
    import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
    import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

        /**
         *
         * @author 
         */
        public class WordReader {

            /**
             *
             * @param filename
             * @return
             * @throws java.io.IOException
             */
            public Map<String, Long> count(String filename) throws IOException {
                //Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename));
                Path path = Paths.get(":");
                Map<String, Long> wordMap = Files.lines(path)
                        .parallel()
                        .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.trim().split(" ")))
                        .map(word -> word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase().trim())
                        .filter(word -> word.length() > 0)
                        .map(word -> new SimpleEntry<>(word, 1))
                        //.collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> 1, Integer::sum));
                        .collect(groupingBy(SimpleEntry::getKey, counting()));

                wordMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(String.format(k,v)));
                return wordMap;
            }
        }
```

I believe I have a issue with calling the WordReader class (Highlighted in **BOLD**) which stops the counter, but I don't know how to resolve it and I've tried to move the class call into the for loop without success. If I comment out the lines, then the file counter runs just fine. Does anyone know I can do to make this program "walk (count files) and chew gum(count words in files)"?

Comment: You're probably getting an exception that the file ":" doesn't exists, check `Path path = Paths.get(":");`.

Comment: I did, but even when I type an actual file Ex: haiku.txt , the same thing happens.

Comment: Print the exception that you catch in main, with `ex.printStackTrace();`

Comment: If I type a path to the directory, then I get an error : Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Is a directory

Comment: Added throws IOException to main, but same error unless I go back to Path path = Paths.get(":"); Should I list the directory path in that line?

Comment: Why don't you use `Path path = Paths.get(filename);`?

Comment: Better is to change `count(String filename)` to `count(Path filePath)`

Comment: I've tried that just now, but the same output occurs. I also tried to add a line at the top of the 'count' method: Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("Files")); , but the same thing occurs

Comment: What? No, thats not how `Files.lines()` works. It takes the path of a single File and returns all lines in it.

Comment: This time I get : Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any> and it lists .filter(word -> word.length() > 0) as the offending line. It's part of the lambda statement in  Map<String, Long> wordMap = Files.lines(path)

Comment: I've commented Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("Files")); out again. back to square one

Comment: `parallel()` is useless here.  You cannot read the lines of a file in parallel (unless you’re certain they’re all exactly the same length, and even then, it will be of little or no help).

Comment: When I've comment out System.out.println("word length: " + fileCounter + " ==> " + 
                        wordCnt.count(path.getFileName().toString())); in the main method then it counts the files: short.txt
tiny.txt . . . , but it nixes the word count

Answer (score 0):

Here are some mistakes which you made:

- passing only the filename to `count()`, because the file is in a directory it's better to pass the whole path.
- using the path of `:`, even it's not a valid filename!
- Not logging the exception that is thrown, you are hiding the real problem.
- Using lambda when you still struggle with most of the java lang.

---

This should work:

Main.class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("files"));
            int fileCounter = 0;
            WordReader wordCnt = new WordReader();
            for (Path path : directoryStream) {
                System.out.println(path.getFileName());
                fileCounter++;
                fileNames.add(path.getFileName().toString());
                System.out.println("word length: " + fileCounter + " ==> " + wordCnt.count(path));
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Count: " + fileNames.size() + " files");
    }
}
```

WordReader.class:

```
public class WordReader {
    public Map<String, Integer> count(Path filePath) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Integer> wordMap = Files.lines(filePath)
                .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.trim().split(" ")))
                .map(word -> word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase().trim())
                .filter(word -> word.length() > 0)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s->s, Collectors.counting()));

        wordMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(String.format(k, v)));
        return wordMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are probably just making it worse adding `parallel` for Files processing here

Comment: @Eugene `parallel` is removed, i only modified the parts from the code with caused trouble.