# Count all the words in a file using java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, cpu-word, distinct-values

I was trying to count the number of unique words in a text file. For the sake of simplicity, my current file content is:

> This is a sample file

My attempt is:

```
long wordCount = 
    Files.lines(Paths.get("sample.txt"))
         .map(line -> line.split("\\s+"))
         .distinct()
         .count();
System.out.println(wordCount);
```

This compiles and runs fine, but results in `1`, while it should be `5`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count words in a text file, java 8-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594679/how-to-count-words-in-a-text-file-java-8-style)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are mapping each line to an array (transforming a `Stream<String>` to a `Stream<String[]>`, and then count the number of array elements (i.e. the number of lines in the file).

You should use `flatMap` to create a `Stream<String>` of all the words in the file, and after the `distinct()` and `count()` operations, you'll get the number of distinct words.

```
long wordCount = 
    Files.lines(Paths.get("sample.txt"))
         .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+")))
         .distinct()
         .count();
```

Comment: It might be more efficient not to scan for line breaks when you only want to count words, i.e. in Java 9: `new Scanner(Paths.get("sample.txt")) .findAll("\\S+") .map(MatchResult::group) .distinct() .count()`. Another advantage of this approach is that it won’t treat empty lines as words. In either case, whether you use `Files.lines` or `Scanner.find`, the resource should be closed after use in production code.

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be counting the lines in your file instead :

```
map(line -> line.split("\\s+")) // this is a Stream<String[]>
```

You shall further use [`Stream.flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) as:

```
long wordCount = Files.lines(Paths.get("sample.txt"))
        .map(line -> line.split("\\s+"))
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .distinct()
        .count();
```